# Magento2 update custom column value in sales order grid table

Tags: magento2, grid

Magento2 I have added custom column in sales_order. I am updating its value via CRON but how can I use same value in sales_order_grid

Below code is use to update sales_order

```
 $order = $this->orderRepository->get($order->getId()); //1 is your order ID
                $order->setCustomValue(2);
                $this->orderResourceModel->save($order);
```

Please guide to update grid value as well

Comment: did you use extension attribute concept for saving this value or directly save the value like that ?

Answer (score 0):

add the same column to your sales_order_grid table and then add this code in di.xml file

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns">
            <item name="shippingaccntno" xsi:type="string">sales_order.shippingaccntno</item>
         
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

here shippingaccntno is a custom field added in sales_order and sales_order grid.